# Tableau - Condition Logic Bad character Error

Tags: conditional-statements, tableau-api

I am currently taking a class on how to use Tableau.

My formula looks like this:

```
IF(ISNULL([Profit Adj])==False && ISNULL([Budget Adj]) ==FALSE)
then (([Profit Adj] - [Budget Adj]) / [Budget Adj])
else Null
end
```

I am trying to create a calculated function.

I am getting the following error message on the `&&` part:

> Bad Character

Why is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF(ISNULL([Profit Adj])==False AND ISNULL([Budget Adj]) ==FALSE)
then (([Profit Adj] - [Budget Adj]) / [Budget Adj])
else Null
end
```

Apparently, I am supposed to use `AND` and not `&&`.

Now I am good.

Comment: It would read better to use "not is null([xxx])" instead of testing equality with FALSE. Also, no need to type "else null". That's the default behavior if there is no else clause